# Ubuntu 14.04 - Oracle JDK 8 - Where is the JAVA_HOME environment variable defined?

Tags: java, oracle, ubuntu

I am trying to uninstall Oracle jdk 8 on my Ubuntu 14.04 server, in order to replace it with open jdk 8 because open source ftw. I have run apt-get purge, apt-get autoclean, logged out, logged back in, and when I run the env command, I see the following:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

I do not want to overwrite this value in my .bashrc file, I do not want to take shortcuts or apply band aids, I want to fix the problem at the source by finding where it is set and removing it. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I ran the following command to find files with the old jdk path:

```
sudo find / -type f -exec grep -Flm 1 '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle' {} +
```

The culprits were in the following directory:

/etc/profile.d